# Angularjs evaluate jquery Math Library expression in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I would like to evaluate this below expression (which contain `ternary operator` and `Javascript Math Library` keywords) in a single variable like

> var result =EvaluatedResult;

which should give me single value, from there I will use that value for another calculation.

```
((((((5-1))/((Math.sqrt((1.3*3.4*((2+273)))/56)))) < 0.3)?(((((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68)<1)?((24/((((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68)))):(((((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68)>1 && (((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68)<1000)?(((24/(((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68))*(1+(0.15*(Math.pow((((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68),0.687)))))):(0.044))):((((((5-1))/((Math.sqrt((1.3*3.4*((2+273)))/56)))) > 0.3) && ((((5-1))/((Math.sqrt((1.3*3.4*((2+273)))/56))))<1))?(((24/((((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68)+((((5-1))/((Math.sqrt((1.3*3.4*((2+273)))/56))))*Math.sqrt((((52)*((2+273)))/(Math.sqrt(2)*(3.14)*(Math.pow(3,2))*(9)))/2))*(4.33+(((3.65-1.53)*((2+273)/2))/(1-0.353*((2+273)/2)))*Math.exp(-0.247*((((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68)/((((5-1))/((Math.sqrt((1.3*3.4*((2+273)))/56))))*Math.sqrt((((52)*((2+273)))/(Math.sqrt(2)*(3.14)*(Math.pow(3,2))*(9)))/2)))))))+((((4.5+0.38)*((0.03*(((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68))+(0.48*Math.sqrt((((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68)))))/(1+((0.03*(((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68))+(0.48*Math.sqrt((((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68))))))+(0.1*Math.pow(((((5-1))/((Math.sqrt((1.3*3.4*((2+273)))/56))))),2))+0.2*Math.pow(((((5-1))/((Math.sqrt((1.3*3.4*((2+273)))/56))))),8))*(Math.exp(-(((5-1))/((Math.sqrt((1.3*3.4*((2+273)))/56))))/(2*Math.sqrt((((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68)))))+(0.6*((((5-1))/((Math.sqrt((1.3*3.4*((2+273)))/56))))*Math.sqrt(62/2)))*(1-(Math.exp(-((((5-1))/((Math.sqrt((1.3*3.4*((2+273)))/56))))/(((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68))))))):(((((5-1))/((Math.sqrt((1.3*3.4*((2+273)))/56))))>1 && (((5-1))/((Math.sqrt((1.3*3.4*((2+273)))/56))))<1.75)?((((24/((((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68)+(1*Math.sqrt((((52)*((2+273)))/(Math.sqrt(2)*(3.14)*(Math.pow(3,2))*(9)))/2))*(4.33+(((3.65-1.53)*((2+273)/2))/(1-0.353*((2+273)/2)))*Math.exp(-0.247*((((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68)/(1*Math.sqrt((((52)*((2+273)))/(Math.sqrt(2)*(3.14)*(Math.pow(3,2))*(9)))/2)))))))+((((4.5+0.38)*((0.03*(((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68))+(0.48*Math.sqrt((((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68)))))/(1+((0.03*(((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68))+(0.48*Math.sqrt((((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68))))))+(0.1*Math.pow((1),2))+0.2*Math.pow((1),8))*(Math.exp(-1/(2*Math.sqrt((((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68)))))+(0.6*(1*Math.sqrt(62/2)))*(1-(Math.exp(-(1/(((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68))))))+((4/3)*((((5-1))/((Math.sqrt((1.3*3.4*((2+273)))/56))))-1)*(((0.9+(1.86*Math.sqrt((1.75)/((((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68))))*(2+2/(Math.pow((1.75*(Math.sqrt((((52)*((2+273)))/(Math.sqrt(2)*(3.14)*(Math.pow(3,2))*(9)))/2))),2)))+(1.058*Math.sqrt((2+273))/(1.75*Math.sqrt((((52)*((2+273)))/(Math.sqrt(2)*(3.14)*(Math.pow(3,2))*(9)))/2)))-(Math.pow(1/(1.75*Math.sqrt((((52)*((2+273)))/(Math.sqrt(2)*(3.14)*(Math.pow(3,2))*(9)))/2))),4)+(0.34/(Math.pow(1.75,2))))/(1+(1.86*Math.sqrt((1.75)/((((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68))))))-((24/((((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68)+(1*Math.sqrt((((52)*((2+273)))/(Math.sqrt(2)*(3.14)*(Math.pow(3,2))*(9)))/2))*(4.33+(((3.65-1.53)*((2+273)/2))/(1-0.353*((2+273)/2)))*Math.exp(-0.247*((((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68)/(1*Math.sqrt((((52)*((2+273)))/(Math.sqrt(2)*(3.14)*(Math.pow(3,2))*(9)))/2)))))))+((((4.5+0.38)*((0.03*(((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68))+(0.48*Math.sqrt((((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68)))))/(1+((0.03*(((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68))+(0.48*Math.sqrt((((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68))))))+(0.1*Math.pow((1),2))+0.2*Math.pow((1),8))*(Math.exp(-1/(2*Math.sqrt((((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68)))))+(0.6*(1*Math.sqrt(62/2)))*(1-(Math.exp(-(1/(((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68)))))))))):(((0.9+(1.86*Math.sqrt(((((5-1))/((Math.sqrt((1.3*3.4*((2+273)))/56)))))/((((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68))))*(2+2/(Math.pow(((((5-1))/((Math.sqrt((1.3*3.4*((2+273)))/56))))*(Math.sqrt((((52)*((2+273)))/(Math.sqrt(2)*(3.14)*(Math.pow(3,2))*(9)))/2))),2)))+(1.058*Math.sqrt((2+273))/((((5-1))/((Math.sqrt((1.3*3.4*((2+273)))/56))))*Math.sqrt((((52)*((2+273)))/(Math.sqrt(2)*(3.14)*(Math.pow(3,2))*(9)))/2)))-(Math.pow(1/((((5-1))/((Math.sqrt((1.3*3.4*((2+273)))/56))))*Math.sqrt((((52)*((2+273)))/(Math.sqrt(2)*(3.14)*(Math.pow(3,2))*(9)))/2))),4)+(0.34/(Math.pow((((5-1))/((Math.sqrt((1.3*3.4*((2+273)))/56)))),2))))/(1+(1.86*Math.sqrt(((((5-1))/((Math.sqrt((1.3*3.4*((2+273)))/56)))))/((((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68)))))))))) * (Math.pow((5-1),2))*(3.14*(Math.pow(3.7,2))/4))
```

When I tried using `$scope.$eval(expression)` then it is able to parse `ternary operator` but not able to parse `Math.pow(3,2)`,`Math.sqrt(2)` like `Javascript Math Library`.
I have done some experiments using expression in HTML which is able to do that.

> http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Veprqx

But I need the result in angularjs scope variable.

Comment: What is jQuery Math Library ? Expression returns `782.7423490194351` here; is this expected result ?

Comment: Sorry it is Javascript Math Library. Library is something similar to Math.pow(3,2) which is a square of 3. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_math.asp.

Comment: How did you do that. Are you able to place the result in $scope variable??

Comment: _"How did you do that."_ `console.log(/* expression */)`

Comment: Can you pass over fiddle or codepen to me?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1fk5q0x5/

Comment: Hey can you write your comment as answer so that i can mark your answer as correct Answer. By the way I didn't know your name. You are very helpful. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not certain what expected result is, though should be able to return results of expression using `var expr = /* mathematical expression */; console.log(expr)`. Note also, [`Math`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math) object is not a "Library" , but an object within [`JavaScript`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)

```js
var expr = ((((((5-1))/((Math.sqrt((1.3*3.4*((2+273)))/56)))) < 0.3)?(((((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68)<1)?((24/((((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68)))):(((((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68)>1 && (((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68)<1000)?(((24/(((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68))*(1+(0.15*(Math.pow((((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68),0.687)))))):(0.044))):((((((5-1))/((Math.sqrt((1.3*3.4*((2+273)))/56)))) > 0.3) && ((((5-1))/((Math.sqrt((1.3*3.4*((2+273)))/56))))<1))?(((24/((((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68)+((((5-1))/((Math.sqrt((1.3*3.4*((2+273)))/56))))*Math.sqrt((((52)*((2+273)))/(Math.sqrt(2)*(3.14)*(Math.pow(3,2))*(9)))/2))*(4.33+(((3.65-1.53)*((2+273)/2))/(1-0.353*((2+273)/2)))*Math.exp(-0.247*((((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68)/((((5-1))/((Math.sqrt((1.3*3.4*((2+273)))/56))))*Math.sqrt((((52)*((2+273)))/(Math.sqrt(2)*(3.14)*(Math.pow(3,2))*(9)))/2)))))))+((((4.5+0.38)*((0.03*(((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68))+(0.48*Math.sqrt((((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68)))))/(1+((0.03*(((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68))+(0.48*Math.sqrt((((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68))))))+(0.1*Math.pow(((((5-1))/((Math.sqrt((1.3*3.4*((2+273)))/56))))),2))+0.2*Math.pow(((((5-1))/((Math.sqrt((1.3*3.4*((2+273)))/56))))),8))*(Math.exp(-(((5-1))/((Math.sqrt((1.3*3.4*((2+273)))/56))))/(2*Math.sqrt((((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68)))))+(0.6*((((5-1))/((Math.sqrt((1.3*3.4*((2+273)))/56))))*Math.sqrt(62/2)))*(1-(Math.exp(-((((5-1))/((Math.sqrt((1.3*3.4*((2+273)))/56))))/(((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68))))))):(((((5-1))/((Math.sqrt((1.3*3.4*((2+273)))/56))))>1 && (((5-1))/((Math.sqrt((1.3*3.4*((2+273)))/56))))<1.75)?((((24/((((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68)+(1*Math.sqrt((((52)*((2+273)))/(Math.sqrt(2)*(3.14)*(Math.pow(3,2))*(9)))/2))*(4.33+(((3.65-1.53)*((2+273)/2))/(1-0.353*((2+273)/2)))*Math.exp(-0.247*((((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68)/(1*Math.sqrt((((52)*((2+273)))/(Math.sqrt(2)*(3.14)*(Math.pow(3,2))*(9)))/2)))))))+((((4.5+0.38)*((0.03*(((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68))+(0.48*Math.sqrt((((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68)))))/(1+((0.03*(((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68))+(0.48*Math.sqrt((((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68))))))+(0.1*Math.pow((1),2))+0.2*Math.pow((1),8))*(Math.exp(-1/(2*Math.sqrt((((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68)))))+(0.6*(1*Math.sqrt(62/2)))*(1-(Math.exp(-(1/(((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68))))))+((4/3)*((((5-1))/((Math.sqrt((1.3*3.4*((2+273)))/56))))-1)*(((0.9+(1.86*Math.sqrt((1.75)/((((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68))))*(2+2/(Math.pow((1.75*(Math.sqrt((((52)*((2+273)))/(Math.sqrt(2)*(3.14)*(Math.pow(3,2))*(9)))/2))),2)))+(1.058*Math.sqrt((2+273))/(1.75*Math.sqrt((((52)*((2+273)))/(Math.sqrt(2)*(3.14)*(Math.pow(3,2))*(9)))/2)))-(Math.pow(1/(1.75*Math.sqrt((((52)*((2+273)))/(Math.sqrt(2)*(3.14)*(Math.pow(3,2))*(9)))/2))),4)+(0.34/(Math.pow(1.75,2))))/(1+(1.86*Math.sqrt((1.75)/((((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68))))))-((24/((((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68)+(1*Math.sqrt((((52)*((2+273)))/(Math.sqrt(2)*(3.14)*(Math.pow(3,2))*(9)))/2))*(4.33+(((3.65-1.53)*((2+273)/2))/(1-0.353*((2+273)/2)))*Math.exp(-0.247*((((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68)/(1*Math.sqrt((((52)*((2+273)))/(Math.sqrt(2)*(3.14)*(Math.pow(3,2))*(9)))/2)))))))+((((4.5+0.38)*((0.03*(((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68))+(0.48*Math.sqrt((((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68)))))/(1+((0.03*(((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68))+(0.48*Math.sqrt((((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68))))))+(0.1*Math.pow((1),2))+0.2*Math.pow((1),8))*(Math.exp(-1/(2*Math.sqrt((((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68)))))+(0.6*(1*Math.sqrt(62/2)))*(1-(Math.exp(-(1/(((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68)))))))))):(((0.9+(1.86*Math.sqrt(((((5-1))/((Math.sqrt((1.3*3.4*((2+273)))/56)))))/((((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68))))*(2+2/(Math.pow(((((5-1))/((Math.sqrt((1.3*3.4*((2+273)))/56))))*(Math.sqrt((((52)*((2+273)))/(Math.sqrt(2)*(3.14)*(Math.pow(3,2))*(9)))/2))),2)))+(1.058*Math.sqrt((2+273))/((((5-1))/((Math.sqrt((1.3*3.4*((2+273)))/56))))*Math.sqrt((((52)*((2+273)))/(Math.sqrt(2)*(3.14)*(Math.pow(3,2))*(9)))/2)))-(Math.pow(1/((((5-1))/((Math.sqrt((1.3*3.4*((2+273)))/56))))*Math.sqrt((((52)*((2+273)))/(Math.sqrt(2)*(3.14)*(Math.pow(3,2))*(9)))/2))),4)+(0.34/(Math.pow((((5-1))/((Math.sqrt((1.3*3.4*((2+273)))/56)))),2))))/(1+(1.86*Math.sqrt(((((5-1))/((Math.sqrt((1.3*3.4*((2+273)))/56)))))/((((23)*((5-1))*3.7)/2.68)))))))))) * (Math.pow((5-1),2))*(3.14*(Math.pow(3.7,2))/4));

console.log(expr)
```